# How do you iterate by increasing odd numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
start = 370

for number in range(73):
    print(f"{number+1}. {(start)}")
    start = start * 1 +1
```

I am trying to add by increasing odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9, etc.).
I am starting out with 370, 371, 374....
I want the output to last until the 73rd term

Comment: you mean 'iterate' not 'add', right?

Comment: @PierreD Yeah that’s what I meant.

Comment: What's the intention of `start = start * 1 +1`? That just adds 1 to start.

Comment: @jarmod I just thought I had to keep making a new increasing variable starting with one.

Comment: Oh, I'm just realizing that you do indeed want to add values -- I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for odd numbers is `2n + 1`, so replace `start = start * 1 +1` with:

```
start += 2*number + 1
```

First 5 outputs:

```
1. 370
2. 371
3. 374
4. 379
5. 386
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried 3n+1 because I thought that was the formula but it was not it. Thanks for clarifying formula for odd numbers!

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate odd numbers is to use the 3-argument form of `range()`:

```py
start = 370

for number in range(1, 2*73 + 1, 2):
    start += number
    print(start)
```

Gives:

```
371
374
379
...
5411
5554
5699
```